# How to Remove the Dependency of Project Server while migrating to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server, content-migration

I am currently planning to Migrate SP 2010 to SP 2013. The environment of SP 2010 includes Project Server 2010 and lot of sub sites are which was created using PWA template but the features provided by Project Server are not used.

So now the scenario is that while migrating to SP 2013 is there any way to remove the Project Server dependency and migrate those sub sites in SharePoint using any of the available templates in SP 2013.

Please let me know the approach to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult. If nothing changed there isn't a supported way of removing project server from SP2010/2013. So you will have issues migrating from the 2010 to 2013. I think in your case best option will be to create sites in the target and use migration (like ShareGate or RepliWeb) tools to move content to the new on prem farm.

Comment: Thanks @Marek Sarad 
Now I have completed the SharePoint site migration using Database Backup/Restore and upgrade method. And as per my observation all content under PWA site is also migrated only I am getting error for PWA default page while accessing the site, still I am able to access the All Site Content page, Setting page by navigating through URL. 
So my doubt is still I need to migrate those PWA site by using Migration Tool or is it ok to set the different default page for accessing the PWA site ??? 
Note: PWA features are not used in source PWA sites.

Comment: It will depend you your use case, if changing the home page is enough then go for it.